# just a clarification on a solution

Tags: general-topology

[this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77779/iso-cross-product) came up to me while i was looking for solutions for questions like the one in the post.
The question there is

> if $A∈\Bbb R^m$ and $B∈\Bbb R^n$ are compact, then $A×B={(x,y)∈\Bbb R^{​n+m}:x∈A,y∈B}$ is also compact. (x is the cross product).

Because $A$ and $A$ are both compact and they are subsets of $\Bbb R^n $( or $ \Bbb R^m)$ wouldnt it be easier to prove that their cross product is bounded and closed?
It it easy to show that they are closed (for example, by taking a limit point of the cross product and show that every element of that point is a limit point of $A$ and $B$ so it has to be in the cross product)and they are obviously bounded because $A$ and $B$ are bounded , therefore $A \times B$ are compact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a valid proof, **if** you've shown that $\Bbb R^{n+m}$ has the product topology when we see it as $\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^m$ (this is true but does involve some argument) and the Heine-Borel theorem can be used. Boundedness will depend on the metric, so choose the right metric.

The general topology fact that products of two compacta are compact is easier, more direct and have no such extra caveats. Just use the cover definition (or sequential compactness e.g., which works fine for finite or countable products) instead.

Comment: thank you! just one thing: aren't $\Bbb R^{n+m} \cong \Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$ (it is for sure...) ? so it is pretty clear that it has the product topology. But you are right, working with the general topology definiton of compactenss is also easy and proves this claim for more spaces than metric spaces